# What is the right way to upload build folder to production server for create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I'm currently working on a live project. The frontend part of the system is in ReactJS. We are using create-react-app as the starter kit.

We are facing some issues in deploying the application on live server. Earlier we followed the strategy of pushing the code on server and then creating the build on it. But we noticed that so long the build was generating, our site became unavailable. Which does not seem right. Hence we decide to create build folder in developer's local machine and push the build to the server. But now we are receiving a lot of change requests and feature requests, hence I'm planning to move to a robust git branching model. I believe this will create problem with the way we are currently handling our deployment strategy(which is to move the build to production).

It will be really helpful if some one can show us the right direction in handling deployment of ReactJS apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins which can be configured to trigger the build as soon as a code in a branch is checked-in in GIT. I have not worked on Jenkins but surely, I have seen people using Jenkins for such things.

Jenkins will trigger the build in its own environment (or you can create a temp folder for the time being the build is getting generated if Jenkins operates on the server directly) which will generate the output bundle. So your code will not be removed from the server for that while and you can patch your new files to the actual folder (which can also be automated using Jenkins).